# Rails 3.2 Determine last element in each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Given the following code, is there a way to test whether the iteration is on the last record?  I have given a little pseudocode on the line I would like to test.

```
@shipments.each do |shipment|
  puts shipment.id
  puts shipment.desc

  unless shipment.last?  #is there a way to do this line?
    puts "that was the last shipment"
  end
end
```

Comment: You can try on the console : `Array.methods` and see that you can't .

Comment: it was obvious you couldn't.  That's why I asked here.

Comment: One approach is you remove this condition from inside the loop, running the full loop, and just after you use `@shipments.last`

Comment: I can't do that because I do additional work inside the block that I only want to happen if it's not the last iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [#last](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) method you could do something like that, but I believe there should be a better way to achieve this

```
@shipments.each do |shipment|
  puts shipment.id
  puts shipment.desc

  unless shipment == @shipments.last  #is there a way to do this line?
    puts "that was the last shipment"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method, but the closest to this would probably be something like:

```
unless shipment == @shipments.last
```

This assumes you're working with a set of ActiveRecord results, because if `@shipments` was an array such as `[1, 2, 3, 2]`, `2` would match the second element as well as the last.